# Xcode 8.1 simulator choppy animation since upgrade

Tags: ios, animation, ios-simulator, swift2, xcode8

My app was perfectly operating until a few days ago when I was forced to upgrade to Xcode 8.1 from Xcode 7 and Swift 2.3 from Swift 2.

Now the simulator in Xcode 8.1 is really choppy when scrolling and even transition animations are awful.

What do I need to do to get this back to the smooth simulator I had in Xcode 7?

Comment: Is the animation lagging only in simulator or in device also ?

Comment: @Rajat - not sure at this stage and can't check right now so I'll have to get back to you in the morning regarding that

Comment: @Rajat - device seems ok so just simulator thats not smooth

Comment: After opening simulator once press command + T

Comment: That turns on the slow animation - still not exactly smooth so even slow animation a bit ropey

Comment: @RobertyBob Do other apps have the same behavior? What about running the app on the iOS 9 Simulator? Please file a bug report and attach a screen recording of what you are seeing. (QuickTime Player can record the screen on your Mac).